# ImageMagick android convert jpegs to gif

Tags: android, imagemagick, gif, animated-gif, imagemagick-convert

I try to speed up gif encoding, using [ImageMagick port](https://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-ImageMagick) for Android. Everything I found about Magick is terminal commands, but no tutorial or some demo for how to do it programmatically. Here is my encode code, but it doesn't create animated gif, just kind of preview, however logs tell, that it's must be animated and must contain frames:

MagickConverter#createGif:

```
final List<MagickImage> frames = new ArrayList<>();

for (final String bitmapPath : bitmapPaths) {
  final MagickImage image = new MagickImage(new ImageInfo(bitmapPath));
  final QuantizeInfo quantizeInfo = new QuantizeInfo();
  quantizeInfo.setNumberColors(256);
  quantizeInfo.setTreeDepth(4); // 8 is max
  image.quantizeImage(quantizeInfo);
  frames.add(image);
}

Timber.v("Frames: %s", frames.toString()); // first test log
final MagickImage[] images = frames.toArray(new MagickImage[frames.size()]);
final MagickImage finalGif = new MagickImage(images);
finalGif.setDelay(FRAME_FREQUENCY / 10);
finalGif.setImageFormat("gif");
finalGif.setIterations(1000); // temp, want to make infinity loops
Timber.d("Is animated: %b", finalGif.isAnimatedImage());
Timber.d("Has frames: %b, number of frames: %d", finalGif.hasFrames(),
    finalGif.getNumFrames());
final ImageInfo resultInfo = new ImageInfo(path);
Timber.d("Result path: %s", resultInfo.getFileName());
resultInfo.setMagick("gif");
//finalGif.writeImage(resultInfo); // it doesn't write to the file
final byte[] img = finalGif.imageToBlob(resultInfo);
Timber.d("Image bytes count: %d", img.length);

FileUtils.store(img, path);
```